# react-share Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL

Tags: reactjs, react-share

Am using react-share package for social sharing of my web page, but in FacebookShare button it shows an error like **"Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL"**

My Share.js code is:-

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  FacebookShareButton,
  FacebookIcon,
  TwitterShareButton,
  TwitterIcon,
  WhatsappShareButton,
  WhatsappIcon,
} from 'react-share'

const ShareButtons = ({title, url}) => {

    return(
        <div>
        <WhatsappShareButton url={url} title={title}className="share-btn">
           <WhatsappIcon  size={40} round={true}/>
        </WhatsappShareButton>
        <FacebookShareButton url={url} title={title}  className="share-btn">
            <FacebookIcon  size={40} round={true}/>
        </FacebookShareButton>

        <TwitterShareButton url={url} title={title} className="share-btn">
            <TwitterIcon  size={40} round={true} />
         </TwitterShareButton>

    </div>
  )

}
export default ShareButtons
```

in my page:-

```
<ShareButtons title={this.state.package.title} url={window.location.href}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you are using localhost, try with an ip address like 127.0.0.1 or just your ip address,and you should get your url like this

```
  let url = '';
  if (typeof window === 'object') {
    url = String(window.location);
    console.log(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated: try with an IP address like `172.0.0.1`
I assume you meant `127.0.0.1`
Changing it to `127.0.0.1` worked for me.